# How to find a model organism's standard data about proteome size and genome size?

Tags: proteins, database, genomes, animal-models, proteomics

I want to know proteome size(the number of proteins not length) and genome size(length) of model organisms like Caenorhabditis elegans, Saccharomyces cerevisiae etc.

I found [www.uiprot.org](http://www.uiprot.org)

and I made a table which is wrong according to my prof.

[image]

for example, I searched "Saccharomyces cerevisiae" on the site.
https://www.uniprot.org/proteomes/UP000002311

[image]

I wrote 6,049 on protein. and clicked the link "GCA_000146045.2 from ENA/EMBL" on Genome assembly and annotation.
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/browser/view/GCA_000146045.2

[image]

I clicked "Assembly Statistics" on the right box and wrote the total length.

where am I wrong?
It seems there are so many samples about a species. I don't know **which is standard reference for the model organism.** I want data as a general knowledge like on the text book

and I found model organism database sites on wiki
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_organism_database
I don't know **how to use these sites**. they give me complicated sequence browsing but I only want just proteome, genome size. what should I do?

---

EDIT.

professor didn't tell us about strains. he just gave the table at the top of this post with data about E.coli by red text as a example.
[image]
this is what professor showed on his next lecture, which is other student's answer.
professor didn't mention which is correct or wrong, he asked if the student is sure about the source(Yu Nie) and if the source is reliable.

anyway, comparing this to my table, Mus musculus and Drosophila have significant difference.

Mus musculus other: 39,412, mine: 55,474
Drosophila other: 30,443, mine: 22,117

I searched again about these.

[image]

[image]

Mus musculus have only two result, it seems I should have chosen standard rather than close to standard.

[image]

but about drosphila, they have no standard. (I chose random one)
https://www.uniprot.org/proteomes/?query=drosophila+melanogaster&sort=busco&desc=no

where can I find about Drosophila?

Comment: when your professor asks about proteome size, do they mean _number_ of proteins or _length_ of proteins? usually the second is what is meant.

Comment: @Maximilian Press number of proteins.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your method -- uniprot is a good resource. If your professor expects statistics for specific species / strains, they should supply unique identifiers or accession numbers for those organisms, at least. Did they give more information about which numbers in your table are wrong, specifically? Can you quote the wording of the assignment?

Comment: @acvill I added what you asked.